# Kubernetes upgrade rolled back machine type

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

My kubernetes cluster is running in Google Container Engine.

Once before I changed the machine-type by using a different instance template.

I am upgrading the kubernetes cluster with following command

```
gcloud container clusters upgrade CLUSTER_NAME --master
gcloud container clusters upgrade CLUSTER_NAME --cluster-version=1.2.1
```

After the upgrading,  it seems the NODE is rolled back to previous instance template. How to upgrade the cluster without losing my instance template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an upgrade, GKE creates a new instance template with the machine type specified in your cluster (the `MACHINE_TYPE` column of the output of `gcloud container clusters list`). So for now, after any node upgrade, you would have to go change the machine-type of the instance template again.

Comment: Hope kubernetes can develop a new feature to allow modify the machine type after cluster creation